# Sudbery's Quantum Mechanics and the Particles of Nature, Chapter 1, Problem 2: Calculate the mass of the electron

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mass, electrons, unit-conversion

I'm currently working on the problems for Chapter 1 of *Quantum Mechanics and the Particles of Nature: An outline for mathematicians* by Anthony Sudbery (Cambridge University Press, 1986; reprinted (with corrections) 1988, 1989).

I'm stumped by one of the problems, problem 2:

> 2. Calculate the mass of the electron in kg. [A charge of 1 coulomb falling through a potential difference of 1 volt acquires energy of 1 joule. The speed of light is $3 \times 10^8 ms^{-1}$. All other necessary information can be found in this chapter.]

The issue I'm having with this problem is that, naively interpreted, it's too easy. On page 3, we are told that by experiments of Faraday, Wilson, and Millikan, the charge of an electron is $1.6 \times 10^{-19}$ coulomb, and that by J. J. Thompson's experiments, the charge-to-mass ratio of the electron is known (but not given explicitly in the text), which then gives the mass of the electron as $9.1 \times 10^{-28} g$. Given that, all I would have to do is convert from grams to kilograms. :-)

So, I assume there's more to this problem, but I can't tell exactly what. I've searched online, and I've gotten the impression that it's actually difficult to calculate the mass of the electron, and that most sources seem to go back to variations of J.J. Thompson's experiment.

I have the feeling that Sudbery has something else in mind, but I can't figure out what. There are a couple of relativity formulas in the text: $E = \sqrt{p^2 + m^2 c^2}$ (which seems to be incorrect; it should be $E = \sqrt{p^2 c^2 + m^2 c^4}$, no?) and $p = Ev/c^2$, and a couple of simple quantum mechanics formulas (e.g., uncertainty principle, $p = h/\lambda$). There are a few other formulas but I don't see their relevance.

All I've been able to do with this problem is to show that $1 eV = 1.6 \times 10^{-19}$ joules. Does anyone know what I should do next? Or is this just a bad problem?

Comment: I'd say: Bad problem, ignore and move on. Don't let it confuse you.

Comment: You are correct that this should be $m^2 c^4$ and I would say that probably he wants you to convert $0.511\text{ MeV},$ mentioned earlier in the chapter as the rest mass of the electron, into $\text{kg},$ given the two pieces of information given. That is, you should be able to substitute (0.511) * (1 million) * (electron charge in C) * (1 volt) to get a mass in Joules, then divide by c^2 to get a mass in kg.

Comment: @CR_Drost Thanks, I think that must be it. It's vaguely unsatisfying (how was the value 0.511 MeV obtained? Probably by the reverse of your calculation!) but it uses all the information supplied in the problem plus an easter egg hunt through the chapter.